# Do U.S. citizens need visa for short term stay in london?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, visa-free-entry

I am US citizen. Do I need UK visa for short stay as voluntary research student. My finance will be cared by my college in us and my parents.

B.Shah

Comment: What do you mean by short stay? How long is it going to be?

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned you are a US citizen, so you will get 6 months entry on arrival at any UK airport, they will simply stamp your US passport and enter a date and a code manually,

that's what they did to me 4 months ago,

i hope this will help you to plan your trip,

Enjoy your trip.

Source: https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/united-kingdom.html (although this says only 90 days but experience and all sorts of unofficial sources claim six months).

The visitor rules are at [UK Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules). These should be examined prior to departure.

The UK Site's [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) determines which nationalities require a visa.

Comment: I updated your answer. It's three months not six and you didn't specify a source.

Comment: thanks for the modification , they wrote 6 months with black pen on top of the entry stamp, might be by mistake VO wrote 6.

Comment: I updated again. https://gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview says six months on a visa and probably the same stay applies visa free but I can't find the length of visa free stays on the gov.uk anywhere.

Comment: @chx all the UK stamps in my US passport say six months.  It's definitely six months (absent unusual circumstances, of course).

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=us&DE=gb&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, except for Nationals of USA for a maximum stay
>   of 6 months.

So no, you do **not** need a visa